# Load data to page elements without freezing the whole Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, lazy-loading

I've a main page with menu options and couple of Iframes.
One of the Iframe page has many DIV elements which are loaded empty initially. So everything loads quickly.

Data fetching queries for each DIV are bit long running. So i want to load data to DIV's one by one without freezing my main page and it's menu options.

How to keep the page alive while data fetching function runs?

Please Suggest.

Comment: you should fetch the data asynchronously. how is your current code?

Comment: Basically you have two options: Using a webworker or use a small setTimeout() in your loop to append data to the dom periodically. But in general it is always best practice to avoid as many DOM operations as possible.

Comment: If it has too many DOM operations, better use some library like react

Answer (score 0):

Have solved It.

Basically, needed to use asynchronous AJAX calls. Command which really saved me was JQuery .ajaxStop(). This command triggers whenever a AJAX command completes. So i call for ajax data for my first element and rest, i keep it under ajax.stop.

So elements loads object data by calling a Asynchronous ajax call. once it completes, it immediately triggers the second element. until all my objects were loaded.

This method is seamless. Page never wait for the data to arrive. Loads as and when the data reached.
My page as several HightChart reports to load.

```
   function startLazyLoading() {
        $("SELECT").each(function (index) {
            filter_load_count++;
            $(this).submit();
            return false;
        });
    }

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("SELECT").each(function (index) {
            if (typeof $(this).attr('onsubmit') !== "undefined") {
                filter_load_count++;
                $(this).submit();
                return false;
               }
          }
    });
```